# how to load a large csv file to bigquery using pandas dataframe in cloud run?

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run

I have csv files in gcs, I want to load them in bigquery, I'm using pandas to ingest files in bigquery, but these files are large (10gb), I use cloud run to execute the job:

```
     df=pd.read_csv(uri,sep=delimiter,dtype = str)

     # Run the load job
     load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table)
```

I always get errors

```
    Memory limit of 512M exceeded with 519M used. Consider increasing the memory limit
```

how to choose the best memory to my cloud run, can I use chunck dataframe  to load data to bigquery
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The bad idea is to increase the [Cloud Run memory](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits). (It's not scalable)

The good idea is to use the [BigQuery CSV import feature](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv). And if you have transforms to perform on your data, you can run a query just after to perform them in SQL.

Comment: Hello guillaume , Thank you for your response. yes I think also increase cloud run it's a bad idea;
I'm using pandas because , I want to load all column as string  , in Bigquery CSV import Feature , I must put a schema or activate the autodetect (these tow option didn't help me ).